# Does growing a RAID 5 destroy the data on the RAID?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

For a linux software RAID using madadm, does adding a harddrive and growing onto the RAID, destroy the data that's already on the RAID or does it preserve everything?

Comment: See lots of related questions http://serverfault.com/search?q=raid5+grow

Answer (score 6):

No, if you add a new drive and grow, you should not loose your data.

If you don't have a tested backup already you should make one.  While nothing should go wrong there is always a small chance that something will go wrong.